# CentOS 6.6 yum update Errno 256 using ISO

Tags: linux, centos, iso-image, yum, centos-6.6

I am running CentOS 6.6 trying to update to 6.8 using an ISO file I downloaded from a mirror for an offline virtual machine.

I have mounted the ISO file and place it in the `/media/CentOS/`

I then run the command `yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=c6-media update`

I get as far as the OS finding the updates and ask to confirm, but when the patches start to download all of them return with an `[Errno 256] no more mirrors to try`.  However, I can download the patches individually with no problems.  I just have about 500 patches to install and no desire to do it manually.

I have tried `yum clean headers && yum clean metadata && yum makecache` as well as `yum clean all`

I have also played with marking the media .repo file as enable and disabling all others with no effect.  I have also check that the `TRANS.TBL` file matches with the `repodata` directory.  I know there are similar posts but I could seem to find on that mentions using an offline ISO file.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into the same issues I did, it turns out I had a 64bit ISO and while I was running a 64bit version there were also 32bit packages that needed to be updated at the same time as the 64bit ones.  I ended up downloading the 32bit ISO and creating a repo of both 64bit and 32bit and updating them together